# How to calculate $\int_{-t}^{t} \delta (\tau) d\tau$

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

How to calculate $$\int_{-t}^{t} \delta (\tau) d\tau$$

My attempt is $$\int_{-t}^{t} \delta (\tau) d\tau = \int_{-\infty}^{t} \delta (\tau) d\tau + \int_{-t}^{\infty} \delta (\tau) d\tau - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta (\tau) d\tau= u(t) + u(t) - 1$$

Am I correct?    Not quite sure if I use the correct properties of dirac function. Thanks!

Comment: What is $u$? ${}$

Comment: Is $t$ positive?

Comment: That isn't something you calculate, it equals $1$.  That is actually the definition of the Dirac Delta.  Any integral over an interval that includes $0$ integrates to $1$, and any integral over an interval that does not include $0$ integrates to $0$.

Comment: @ArcticChar unit step signal

Comment: @copper.hat $t$ is arbitrary.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor Thanks! Would you mind letting me know which step I made mistake?

Comment: Dirac's delta is not a function but a probability measure that assigns mass $1$ to $\{0\}$. As a "generalize function" or distribution, it act on  $\mathcal{C}^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ as  $\delta(\phi)=\phi(0)$. It happens to be the derivative off the Heavy side function  $H(t)=\mathbb{1}_[0,\infty)(t)$. (in the sense of distributions) that is $-\int_\mathbb{R}H(t)\phi'(t)=\phi(0)=\delta(\phi)$

Comment: Writing it that way, you should get $1+1-1 = 1$.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor However, $\int_{-\infty}^{t}\delta(\tau)d\tau = u(t)$. If $t<0$, the integral is $0$ not $1$.

Comment: I assumed $t>0$ is implied by the original integral having limits $-t$ to $t$.  But you're right, it could be even more backwards, which puts a minus sign on the whole thing.

Comment: @sleevechen: it seems we are taking about the same thing but in different languages (mathematics and physics). Consider the Heavy side function as a distribution, that is $H(\phi)=\int \mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)}(x)\phi(x)\,dx$ for $\phi\in\mathcal{C}^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$. The convolution of $H$ with any $\phi$ os defined as 
$$t\mapsto H*\phi(t)=\int\mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)}(x)\phi(t-x)\,dx=\int\mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)}(t-x)\phi(x)\,dx=\int^t_{-\infty}\phi(x)\,dx 
$$
Now, the derivative of $H*\phi$ is given by
$$ \phi(t)=D(H*\phi)(t)=(DH*\phi)(t)=(\delta*\phi)(t)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dirac delta is defined by its integrals, not by values, as it is not a function.  $$\int_a^b \delta(t)dt = \begin{cases} 1 & a \leq 0 \leq b \\ 0 & a>0 \text{ or } b < 0\end{cases}$$

Since you are integrating from $-t$ to $t$, your interval includes $0$ so the answer is $1$.  The three integrals you broke it up into evaluate to $1,1,1$ so the sum is $1$, as it should be.  Technically some of those do integrate to the step function, but since $t$ is a given constant, I wasn't really thinking of the step function at all.  However, that is not the usual way to break up an integral's interval.

I *think* the breakdown you wrote is valid, but I've never seen it done that way.  In effect you integrated over $-t$ to $t$ by doing it over all real numbers but including the interval of interest twice and then subtracting the integral over all real numbers.  But again, all of this is unnecessary because there is nothing to prove, the claim is true by definition of the Dirac Delta.

Comment: Just a question here, is the answer always $1$ for all $t$ including negative $t$?

Comment: If you integrate anything backwards you get a minus sign.  I was assuming $t>0$